# Why my Parse Date does not work in the Jupyter

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("c://test//AAPL.csv", parse_dates("Date"), index_col=["Date"])
```

Error message as below: I am a beginner, sorry

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-7cc4dcacdd2e> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df=pd.read_csv("c://test//AAPL.csv", parse_dates("Date"), index_col=["Date"])
      3 df

NameError: name 'parse_dates' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

parse_dates is [kwarg to read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df=pd.read_csv("c://test//AAPL.csv", parse_dates=["Date"], index_col=["Date"])
```

*You were calling it like a function, hence the `NameError`.*